# Adding list items programatically in android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing a basic app

in this app the is a list of skills that the user can add to his profile

what I want to do is:

create an xml file for the item where the user can input all his data (done)

create a custom adapter that can render these .xml file into a listview (done)

create a button that, when pressed, a new item slot will be rendered allowing for the user to input another skill of his (done)

the problem is: everytime I click the button to add a new skill, it erases all data that was input in the previous skill slots. I already tryed using onNotifyDataSetChanged to no avail.

How can I programatically add new items to a listview without erasing the data I have set on all other items

As an example, it's exactly like the phone contacts app, where each contact can have multiple phone numbers / emails / etc

Adapter code:

```
package br.com.jobr.jobr.Utils.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.jobr.jobr.Entities.Support.Skill;
import br.com.jobr.jobr.R;

/**
 * Created by christian.hess on 13/03/2018.
 */

public class NewSkillAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Skill> {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    List<Skill> skills;
    ListView listSkills;

    public NewSkillAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Skill> skills, ListView listSkills) {
        super(context, resource, skills);
        Log.i("NewSkill", "Numero de item: " + skills.size());
        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.skills = skills;
        this.listSkills = listSkills;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View item = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

        final Button bt_new_skill = item.findViewById(R.id.bt_new_skill);
        final Spinner sp_skill_name = item.findViewById(R.id.sp_skill_name);
        final Spinner sp_skill_specialization = item.findViewById(R.id.sp_skill_specialization);


        String[] habilityArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hability_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> habilityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, habilityArray) {
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Disable the first item from Spinner
                    // First item will be use for hint
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Set the hint text color gray
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };
        habilityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_skill_name.setAdapter(habilityAdapter);


        String[] especializationArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.especialization_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> especializationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, especializationArray) {
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Disable the first item from Spinner
                    // First item will be use for hint
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Set the hint text color gray
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };
        especializationAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_skill_specialization.setAdapter(especializationAdapter);


        bt_new_skill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int size = skills.size();
                skills = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    Skill s = (Skill) listSkills.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    skills.add(s);
                }

                skills.add(new Skill("", "", "", ""));
                listSkills.getAdapter().notifyAll();
            }
        });

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that renders your list please ?

Comment: Please, check how do you working the data behind your adapter, probably, you have a List, and it looks like you somehow remove everything that was already there.

Comment: I will post the code in a second

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour leads me to believe you are clearing the data structure on the adapter every time you add a new skill. 
Can you post your adapter code snippet so we visually debug it?

Regards,

@Edit

I believe your problem to be on this specific line

```
            skills = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside your

```
bt_new_skill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int size = skills.size();
            skills = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Skill s = (Skill) listSkills.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                skills.add(s);
            }

            skills.add(new Skill("", "", "", ""));
            listSkills.getAdapter().notifyAll();
        }
    });
```

As you can see, whenever you press the "bt_new_skill" button, you are re-initializing the ArrayList, thus losing all previous records.
I am not fully aware of your code as whole, so keep it in mind if it doesnt fix.

Also, i recommend that you use

```
listSkills.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of

```
listSkills.getAdapter().notifyAll();
```

as the former is the official method to update the data set of the adapter

Comment: this did work, i realized only afterwards the re-initialization of the array

Comment: hi ricardo could please me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview